# How to change superclass member variable when extends

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a supperclass:

```
public abstract class BasicDAO implements DAO{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicDAO.class);
    protected DBCollection Collection;
    @Override
    public DBCursor findByAll() {
        DBCursor cursor = Collection.find();
        log.debug("do something");
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

I extends this superclass:

```
public class TopicBasicDAO extends BasicDAO{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicBasicDAO.class);
}
```

I want to change the member variable log to subclass,but it can't override the member.How can I do?

Comment: you can not override `static` members. they belong to class, not object

Comment: @Adi I know ,but I want to use subclass's log in supperclass method when extends.I think Eran's answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you can't override static members. I'll suggest an alternative. It seems like you need a different logger instance for each class in your hierarchy. This can be handled with a Map.

```
private static Map<Class,Logger> loggers = new HashMap<Class,Logger>();
....
public Logger getLogger ()
{
    Logger logger = null;
    if (BasicDAO.loggers.containsKey(this.getClass())) {
        logger = BasicDAO.loggers.get(this.getClass());
    } else {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        BasicDAO.loggers.put (this.getClass(), logger);
    }
    return logger;
}
```

Then, instead of accessing the logger directly, you write `getLogger().debug("do something");`

Answer (score 0):

Make the log variable protected and not final in superclass, then in your subclass you can modify it,
i.e. in Superclass:

```
protected static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicDAO.class);
```

and in Subclass:

```
public class TopicBasicDAO extends BasicDAO{
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicBasicDAO.class);
}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to declare the Logger as private static final

Comment: this code won't even compile, unless you put it in a static initializer block.